# I have difficulty in setting date

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG9SY.png)
I want to do this but I can't

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zK1qb.png)
I hope you teach me

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [`DropdownButton` widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html)

Here is a code example for using it:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<int>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      elevation: 16,
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      ),
      onChanged: (int? value) {
        // This is called when the user selects an item.
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = value!;
        });
      },
      items: list.map<DropdownMenuItem<int>>((int value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<int>(
          value: value,
          child: Text("$value"),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
```

However, I recommend you using `DatePicker` see the [documentation here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDatePicker.html) since it will be easier to deal with dates in flutter using this widget.